# How to get Class Name given its Property

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

Is it possible to get the class name given the name of its property. If it is then how? Anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for mscorlib.dll. It finds all classes which have property named "Capacity".

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.Load("mscorlib.dll");
foreach (Type type in asm.GetTypes())
{
    foreach (MemberInfo mem in type.GetMembers())
    {
        if ((mem.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property) && (mem.Name == "Capacity"))
            Console.WriteLine(type);
    }
}
```

Or, using LINQ:

```
var asm = Assembly.Load("mscorlib.dll");
foreach (var type in from type in asm.GetTypes()
                     from mem in type.GetMembers()
                     where (mem.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property) &&
                        (mem.Name == "Capacity")
                     select type)
    Console.WriteLine(type);
```

Here is the output:

```
System.Text.StringBuilder
System.Collections.CollectionBase
System.Collections.ArrayList
System.Collections.ArrayList+IListWrapper
System.Collections.ArrayList+SyncArrayList
System.Collections.ArrayList+FixedSizeArrayList
System.Collections.ArrayList+ReadOnlyArrayList
System.Collections.ArrayList+Range
System.Collections.SortedList
System.Collections.SortedList+SyncSortedList
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T]
System.IO.MemoryStream
System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream
System.IO.PinnedBufferMemoryStream
System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryAccessor
System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStreamWrapper
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is directly possible. You will have to search all the classes via reflection and you will have to look for that particular property in each class

Answer (score 2):

If you have a [PropertyInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx) then you could use the [DeclaringType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.declaringtype.aspx) property. If you only have some string you cannot get much from it. You will have to first get the property but to get the property you first need to get the declaring class, so you already know the declaring class.

Answer (score 1):

Reflections are good idea Try to read this article located at MSDN.com http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183(VS.80).aspx